# Is it possible to access $stateProvider, $state in angular application (hybrid approach project, using both Angular JS and Angular 13)

Tags: angular, angularjs

We have a hybrid approach project, using both Angular JS and Angular 13.
In the case of Service (from Angular JS), use getInjectableName() and declare it as a provider in the angular application.

I have a scenario where we defined the $state in AngularJS. from angular I need to use the $state.go('com.abc.employee.details') to navigate to my previous state.

Could anyone please suggest is there any way to do this? like how to access $state, $stateProvider in Angular 13.

Comment: "We have a hybrid approach project, using both Angular JS and Angular 13"  You are better served to back out of this at pretty much any cost.